# Change Airflow Services Logs Path

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am looking for resources to change the log paths for Airflow services such as Webserver and Scheduler. I am running out of space every now and then and so want to move the logs into a bigger mount space.

- airflow-scheduler.log
- airflow-webserver.log
- airflow-scheduler.out
- airflow-webserver.out
- airflow-scheduler.err
- airflow-webserver.err

I am starting the services using below given command:

- airflow webserver -D
- airflow scheduler -D

Thanking in advance!

Answer (score 3):

From https://airflow.apache.org/howto/write-logs.html#writing-logs-locally

> Users can specify a logs folder in airflow.cfg using the base_log_folder setting. By default, it is in the AIRFLOW_HOME directory.

You need to change the `airflow.cfg` for log related parameters as below:

```
[core]
...
# The folder where airflow should store its log files
# This path must be absolute
base_log_folder = /YOUR_MOUNTED_PATH/logs
...

[webserver]
...
# Log files for the gunicorn webserver. '-' means log to stderr.
access_logfile = /YOUR_MOUNTED_PATH/webserver-access.log"
error_logfile = /YOUR_MOUNTED_PATH/webserver-error.log"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Log location can be specified on airflow.cfg as follows. By default, it is under AIRFLOW_HOME

```
[core]
...
# The folder where airflow should store its log files
# This path must be absolute
base_log_folder = /airflow/logs
...
```

Please refer to this for additional information https://airflow.apache.org/howto/write-logs.html?highlight=logs

Answer (score 0):

In both master ([code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/cli.py#L187)) and the 1.10 branch ([code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py#L124)), the locations of the following files are hardcoded unless you pass an argument to the cli:

- airflow-webserver.err
- airflow-webserver.out
- airflow-webserver.log
- airflow-scheduler.err
- airflow-scheduler.out
- airflow-scheduler.log

The *rest* of the log locations can be modified through one of the following variables:

In the `[core]` section:

```
base_log_folder
log_filename_template
log_processor_filename_template
dag_processor_manager_log_location
```

And in the `[webserver]` section:

```
access_logfile
error_logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply flags to the `airflow webserver -D` and `airflow scheduler -D` commands to put all of the generated webserver and scheduler log files where you want them.  Here's an example:

```
airflow webserver -D \
    --port 8080 \
    -A $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/webserver/airflow-webserver.out \
    -E $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/webserver/airflow-webserver.err \
    -l $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/webserver/airflow-webserver.log \
    --pid $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/webserver/airflow-webserver.pid \
    --stderr $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/webserver/airflow-webserver.stderr \
    --stdout $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/webserver/airflow-webserver.stdout
```

and

```
airflow scheduler -D \
    -l $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/scheduler/airflow-scheduler.log \
    --pid $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/scheduler/airflow-scheduler.pid \
    --stderr $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/scheduler/airflow-scheduler.stderr \
    --stdout $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/scheduler/airflow-scheduler.stdout
```

Note: If you use these, you'll need to create the `logs/webserver` and `logs/scheduler` subfolders.  This is only tested for airflow 2.1.2.